# Issues for finding neighbours (Conways Game of Life)

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

```
package GameofLife;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameOfLife {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] world;
        String[][] finalform;
        world = new String[20][20];
        finalform = new String[20][20];
        String alivecell = "A";
        String deadcell = "D";
        int day = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < world.length; a++) {
            for (int a2 = 0; a2 < world.length; a2++) {
                world[a][a2] = deadcell;
                // shows every cell as dead
            }
        }
        int more = 1;// meant for if the player is wanting to add more living
                     // cells onto the game
        while (more == 1) {
            int c = 21;// column
            int r = 21;// row
            while (c > 20 || r > 20) {// since the game is in a 20x20 grid, it
                                      // will loop the code below if the column
                                      // or row is above 20
                System.out.println("Which column do you want a cell to be on?");
                c = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Which row do you want a cell to be on? ");
                r = input.nextInt();
                c = c - 1;
                r = r - 1;
            }
            day = 1;/// a day of living cell(s) has begun
            System.out.println("Day " + day);
            for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
                for (int a2 = 0; a2 < 20; a2++) {
                    world[c][r] = alivecell;// WHICH CELLS SHOULD BE ALIVE
                    System.out.format("%3s", world[a][a2]);// output shown in
                                                           // 20x20 grid
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?");
            more = input.nextInt();
            if (more != 1) {
                game(world, alivecell, deadcell, 0, finalform);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void game(String[][] world, String alivecell, String deadcell, int day,
            String[][] finalform) {/// coming from the pseudo code in the text
                                   /// book
        int cont = 1;
        day++;
        System.out.println("Day " + (day));
        while (cont == (1)) {
            for (int c = 0; c < world.length; c++) {
                for (int r = 0; r < world.length; r++) {
                    int neighbours = n(c, r, world.length, world, alivecell, deadcell); // finds
                                                                                        // neighbours
                    switch (neighbours) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                        world[c][r] = deadcell;
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        world[c][r] = alivecell;
                    default:
                        world[c][r] = deadcell;
                    }
                    System.out.format("%3s", world[c][r]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            // outputs the world with the edits
            System.out.println("continue to next day? press 1 ");
            cont = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static int n(int c, int r, int length, String[][] world, String alivecell,
            String deadcell) {
        int neighbours = 0;
        for (int c2 = (c - 1); c2 <= c + 1; c2++) {
            for (int r2 = (r - 1); r2 <= r + 1; r2++) {
                if ((r > 0) && (r < world.length - 1) && (c > 0) && c < world.length - 1) {
                    if (world[c2][r2] == alivecell) {
                        neighbours++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (r == 0 && c == 0) {// on corners
                if (world[(0 + 1)][(0 + 1)] == alivecell) {
                    neighbours++;
                }
                if (world[0 + 1][0] == alivecell) {
                    neighbours++;
                }
                if (world[0][0 + 1] == alivecell) {
                    neighbours++;
                }
            } else if (r == 0 && c == 19) {
                if (world[19][0] == alivecell) {
                    if (world[(19 - 1)][0 + 1] == alivecell) {
                        neighbours++;
                    }
                    if (world[(19)][0 + 1] == alivecell) {
                        neighbours++;
                    }
                    if (world[(19 - 1)][0] == alivecell) {
                        neighbours++;
                    }
                }
                try {
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
                    if (c == 19 && r != 0) {
                        for (int cno = c - 1; cno <= c; cno++) {
                            for (int rno = r; rno <= r + 1; rno++) {
                                if (world[cno][rno] == alivecell) {
                                    neighbours++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (c == 0 && r != 19) {
                        for (int cno1 = c; cno1 <= c + 1; cno1++) {
                            for (int rno1 = r - 1; rno1 <= r; rno1++) {
                                if (world[cno1][rno1] == alivecell) {
                                    neighbours++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

What I am trying to do here is make the code count the neighbours in each cell that the player prompts to put in what area, whenever I start the game (after I choose where the cell should be), all the cells come out as dead after I start the game.

```
 Which column do you want a cell to be on?
 2
  Which row do you want a cell to be on? 
  2
  Day 1
   D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
   D  A  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?
1
Which column do you want a cell to be on?
2
Which row do you want a cell to be on? 
3
Day 1
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  A  A  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?
1
Which column do you want a cell to be on?
2
Which row do you want a cell to be on? 
4
Day 1
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  A  A  A  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?
2
  Day 1
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
continue to next day? press 1
```

Comment: You do understand what code indentation and formatting is for, right? It's not something whose purpose is just to make code look "pretty" but rather when done correctly to make code much easier to read and to understand. This is doubly important when posting a large code base to folks who you'd like to put in effort to help you, since it is to your great advantage for them to easily understand that code and what you're asking. Why not put in the effort to help us out here? Why not correct your formatting and your indentation so that it conforms to easily found standards, and allow us to help?

Comment: OK, I tried to do some fixing of your code's formatting, but in the future, please do this yourself as this should be the asker's responsibility.

Comment: One major problem jumped out at me: your switch statement has no `breaks` in it -- so the default will always be called -- all cells will be dead.

Answer (score 0):

One problem, your switch statement is broken:

```
switch (neighbours) {
case 0:
case 1:
    world[c][r] = deadcell;
case 2:
case 3:
    world[c][r] = alivecell;
default:
    world[c][r] = deadcell;
}
```

Because there are no `break` statements, the default condition will **always** be called, meaning your cells will be dead no matter the neighbor count. Use breaks to fix this:

```
switch (neighbours) {
case 0:
case 1:
    world[c][r] = deadcell;
    break;
case 2:
case 3:
    world[c][r] = alivecell;
    break;
default:
    world[c][r] = deadcell;
}
```

Another issue is that you appear to be changing your grid as you're checking it, which will lead to false results. You always must use two grids: the one you're checking and the one that holds the next generation result, so that changes made to the 2nd grid while checking the first one, don't have side effects.

And in fact you have another 2D array present just for this purpose, `finalform`, but you don't appear to ever be using it, which begs the question -- why do you have it if you're not using it?

Comment: @W.S: I was more concerned about the actual format of the code itself, and less how it was copied to the site, including the indentations and spacing. But I'm sure that your formatting for future posts will get better. Keep at it.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting issues, its just that I'm new here. i only pressed Cont+K  to separate the code to what i trying to achieve. as for the other 2D array and not putting break statements, that was just me being desperate on trying to finish Game of Life for a school project. I've been doing this for a few weeks now but now it's much more simplified. Also the output was not what i expected, instead of all the cells as dead the living cells are now scattered all over the place now after i placed 3 living cells  in row 2 , but thnx anyway https://gyazo.com/f54611da3a2599601e762112813eee3b

Comment: @W.S: good luck with this assignment. Hope you finish it and get it working. You do understand the problems that I mentioned in my answer above, right?